# Оператор try c ресурсами

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

Зачем нужен усовершенствованный и появившийся в `JDK 7` оператор `try`-c-ресурсами?

```
try (спецификация_ресурса) {
//использование ресурса
{
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `try`-c-ресурсами реализует принцип **автоматического управления ресурсами**, целью которого является избежать, например, утечек памяти, в случаях когда ресурс по каким-то причинам не освобождается, если он больше не нужен.

> Неудачный исход закрытия файла может привести к "утечкам памяти", поскольку неиспользуемые ресурсы оперативной памяти останутся выделенными.([стр 365](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/))

```
try ( FileInputStream res = new FileInputStream(args[O])) {

    //использование ресурса

}
```

Оператор `try`-c-ресурсами позволяет объявить и проинициализировать ресурс (в круглых скобках после оператора `try`), создав переменной ресурса локальный контекст в блоке `try`. По завершении этого блока переменная удаляется, а значит и ресурс автоматически закрывается.

Отсюда отпадает необходимость явного закрытия ресурса методом `close()` в блоке оператора `finally`.

Comment: Ну только не памяти, за памятью сборщик мусора следит.

Comment: @Qwertiy если в обычном `try` забыть закрыть ресурс утечки памяти не будет, сработает сборщик мусора?

Comment: Насколько я представляю, утечь могут только нативные ресурсы. Память должна всё равно очиститься сборщиком мусора. В случае с файлом может остаться открытый хэндл с локом на файл - минимум до сборки мусора (точнее не знаю, в джаве не очень разбираюсь, но в шарпе было бы до неё, потому что финализатор подчистит).

Answer (score 3):

`try-catch with resources` был придумал лишь для того, чтобы избежать шаблонного кода.

Давайте попробуем написать, простой метод, для чтения первой строки из файла. До **java 7** он выглядел бы следующим образом:

```
private static String readFirstLine(String fileName) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        line = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

Заметили, что в блоке `catch` нам нужен еще один блок для обработки исключений, т.к. мы должны закрыть ресурс, но операция закрытия в свою очередь тоже может выбросить исключение.

Не стоит так же забывать, что `try-catch with resources` позволяет не думать об освобождении ресурсов. Как только выполнение программы покидает область видимости ресурса/ресурсов, у них автоматические вызывается метод `java.lang.AutoCloseable.close()`

По сути, данную конструкцию можно представить, как метод, который принимает на вход какой то блок кода, требующий выполнения и список ресурсов, которые необходимо освободить после его выполнения.

```
private static void invoke(Callable<Void> task, Closeable... resources) throws Exception {
    Exception exception = null;

    try {
        task.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
    } finally {
        for (Closeable closeable : resources)
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (exception == null)
                    exception = e;
                else
                    exception.addSuppressed(e);
            }
    }

    if (exception != null)
        throw exception;
}
```