# Java try конструкция в try

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

```
try {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(FILENAME), "UTF8"))) {
        bw.write(UNICODE_STRING);
        bw.flush();
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UnicodeWriteExample.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UnicodeWriteExample.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Имеется ли смысл вкладывать `try{}` в еще один `try{}` ? Ведь можно было обойтись одним

Comment: Я обычно не вкладываю. Юзаю один

Comment: Учитывая, что вокруг вложенного try нет ни строчки кода - это свершенно бессмысленное действо)

Comment: То ли связанный вопрос, то ли дубликат: [Оператор try c ресурсами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619509) (зачем комменты удаляем?)

Comment: я не совсем хотел удалять, я просто хотел пожаловаться и оно само так вышло )

Comment: А жаловаться зачем?)

Comment: Комментарий устаревший, многословный или НЕЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНЫЙ по иной причине.

Comment: Почему устаревший или нежелательный по какой причине?

Comment: я же спрашивал не _Оператор try c ресурсами_, а зачем нужен вложенный try в try.)

Comment: Внутренний try работает с ресурсами, корректно закрывая файл, внешний try ловит ошибки — вроде это должно стать понятно после чтения вопроса [Оператор try c ресурсами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619509)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае код можно переписать таким образом (убрав один try) :

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(FILENAME), "UTF8"))) {
    bw.write(UNICODE_STRING);
    bw.flush();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UnicodeWriteExample.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UnicodeWriteExample.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Но т.к у вас выполняются абсолютно одинаковые действия, то не имеет смысла ловить исключения разных типов:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(FILENAME), "UTF8"))) {
    bw.write(UNICODE_STRING);
    bw.flush();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UnicodeWriteExample.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

В общем случае конструкций вида : try try catch catch желательно избегать, т.к такой код трудно читать.